# How RealVNC works?

Tags: vnc

I would to know how RealVNC remote viewer works.

It frequently send screenshots to the client in real time ?

or does it use other approach ?

Comment: Why the "not a real question" votes? This question sounds OK to me.

Comment: @peoro: While I could (barely) bring myself to interpret this as a programming question, what does it have to do with C or C++?

Comment: @sbi: tags were wrong without any doubt, but that doesn't make this a non-real question.

Comment: I would say this is a programmers.stackexchange question, not a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a very high-level overview, there are two types of VNC servers:

1. Screen-grabbing.  These servers will capture the current display into a buffer, compare it to the client state, and send *only the rectangles that differ* to the client.
2. Hook-assisted.  Hooking into the display update process, these servers will be informed when the screen changes by the display manager or OS.  They can then use that information to send only the changed rectangles to the client.

In both cases, it is effectively a stream of screen updates; however, only the *changed* regions of the screen are transmitted to the client.  Depending on the version of the VNC protocol in use, these updates may be compressed as well.

(Note that the client is free to request a complete screen update any time it wants to, but the server will only do this on its own if the entire screen is changed.)

Also, screen updates are not the only things transmitted.  There are separate channels that the server can use to send clipboard updates and mouse position updates (since a user physically at the remote machine may be able to move the mouse too).

Comment: can u plzz tell me how to send only change region of the screen. how people actually do this. suppose we can compare two image and find out the difference but when i will send the difference to remote pc then what logic i need to use to stitch the change region in the prev image. i search google lot but found no details discuss how people do this. is there any article which guide me to do this in real life. thanks

Comment: @Thomas What does this have to do with VNC?

Answer (score 5):

> The display side of the protocol is
>   based around a single graphics
>   primitive: “put a rectangle of pixel
>   data at a given x,y position”. At
>   first glance this might seem an
>   inefficient way of drawing many user
>   interface components. However,
>   allowing various different encodings
>   for the pixel data gives us a large
>   degree of flexibility in how to trade
>   off various parameters such as network
>   bandwidth, client drawing speed and
>   server processing speed. A sequence of
>   these rectangles makes a framebuffer
>   update (or simply update). An update
>   represents a change from one valid
>   framebuffer state to another, so in
>   some ways is similar to a frame of
>   video. The rectangles in an update are
>   usually disjoint but this is not
>   necessarily the case.

Read [here](http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf) to find out more how it works

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It just sends some sort of screenshots (compressed and which reuses unchanged portions of the previous screenshot).

This is by the way the VNC protocol, any client work that way (although the actual way to compress images etc etc may change).

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the server sends Frame Buffer Updates to the client and the client sends keyboard and mouse input and frame buffer update requests to the server.

Frame Buffer Update messages can have different encodings, but in essence they are different ways of representing square screen areas of pixel data. Generally the client asks for Frame Buffer Updates for the entire screen but it can ask for just an area of the screen (for example, small screen clients showing a viewport of the servers screen). The server then sends a FBU (frame buffer update) that contains rectangles where the screen has changed since the last FBU was sent to the client.

The best reference for the RFB/VNC protocol is [here](https://github.com/rfbproto/rfbproto/blob/master/rfbproto.rst). The IETF has a recent (2011) standards document [RFC 6143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6143) that covers RFB although it is not an extensive as the reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

It essentially works by sending screenshots on the fly.  ("Real time" is something of a misnomer here in that there is no clear deadline.)  It does attempt to optimize by only sending areas of the screen that have changed, and some forks of the VNC code line use a mirror driver to receive notification when areas of the display are written to, while others use window message hooks to detect repaint requests.