# How to send frame buffer update in VNC?

Tags: c, vnc, vnc-server

I am working on designing a VNC server. According to the standard VNC/RFB protocol, I get a frame buffer request containing x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate, width and height. My server has to send the "changed regions only i.e. send only the rectangles that differ to the client".

I know it was already answered in "[How RealVNC works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833152/how-realvnc-works)". But my question is
a) How do I send only the rectangles which are changed?
b) How do we know that the update has to be sent in "these" many rectangles?

And this same question was asked in "[RFB Protocol : Send incremental framebuffer update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746374/rfb-protocol-send-incremental-framebuffer-update) ", but there is no response..
Please help me solving this. I am working in C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you having your VNC server display - the user's desktop? If so, what OS are you writing the client for?

Comment: @duskwuff: U can say its displaying user's desktop. For eg. if a mobile is connected to car infotainment system, my server will be on mobile side. so basically I need to send my mobile screen. So it should be able to display a video or a screen shot of image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused about the standard.

[RFB Standard](http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf)

> However, if for some reason the client has lost the contents of a
>   particular area which it needs, then the client sends a
>   FramebufferUpdateRequest with incremental set to zero (false). This
>   requests that the server send the entire contents of the speciﬁed area
>   as soon as possible. The area will not be updated using the CopyRect
>   encoding

This means that if you get an incremental request, you send the entire section, because the client has forgotten what goes there.  You can send this section in whatever configuration of rectangles you see fit.

[RFB Standard](http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf)

> If the client has not lost any contents of the area in which it is
>   interested, then it sends a FramebufferUpdateRequest with incremental
>   set to non-zero (true). If and when there are changes to the speciﬁed
>   area of the framebuffer, the server will send a FramebufferUpdate.

This means if you get a non incrimtal request( incremental flag set to true, I know, its dumb), you send any changes that have occured on the screen.

> b) How do we know that the update has to be sent in "these" many rectangles?

You can send the updates in any combination of rectangles that you wish.  Although I have witnessed Clients that crash from sending updates in funky orders.  But you can send 1 rectangle or 1000 rectangles, it's up to you.